# Why will this query only produce 1 row and not 2? And why does it have a value of 11 and not 1?

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

**What do I need to change to make this query output 2 rows, first value 1 and second value 10?**

```
CREATE TABLE cars (car_id NUMBER, top_speed NUMBER);

CREATE SEQUENCE car_counter START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 10;

INSERT INTO cars VALUES (car_counter.NEXTVAL, ‘Ninety’);

INSERT INTO cars VALUES (car_counter.NEXTVAL, 200);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I am not oracle DBA but math can help somtimes. CREATE SEQUENCE car_counter START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
INSERT INTO cars VALUES (car_counter.NEXTVAL * 10, ‘Ninety’);

Comment: You can always try [a fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

1. It produces 1 row because 'Ninety' is not a number so the first insert failed
2. Even though the first insert failed, it still consumed a number from `car_counter` (i.e., 1), then Oracle increment the sequence by 10 to 11 for next value.
3. You can change the sequence to `INCREMENT BY 9` so that first value is 1, second is 10, but the third is 19. You may `START WITH 10` or even 100 if you want things end with 0.